# Is there a way to monitor files and shell commands asynchronously in ruby?

Tags: ruby, observer-pattern

I'm writing a ruby program to show me a status bar. It shows me things like my volume and brightness. I want to make it update whenever the volume or brightness changes on my computer (right now all it does is update every second). What I think I want is something like:

```
clNotifier = INotify::Notifier.new
clNotifier.watch("/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness", :modify) {
  # update my bar
}

IO.popen("pactl subscribe | grep sink").each do |line|
  # update my bar
end
```

The notifier is watching a particular file that controls brightness, and the command being run in popen outputs stuff when the volume changes if I just run it in a terminal. But when I run this code, it doesn't seem to run the code in either block when I expect.

I think I actually have two problems/questions. First, can I get both of these to work simultaneously? Second, is there something special about the pipe in the command that I need to pay attention to?

Comment: It's one thing to watch asynchronously a file change, and it's another to keep your program running. To do that, you need to loop infinitely. So are you sure you need an asynchronous check in that case ?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Do I need to have `while 1` at the end of my code? When I have a notifier and run the script from the command line, it keeps outputting to standard out when the file gets changed.